# Supporting Multiple Android Versions using the Google APIs Add On

Tags: android, api, google-maps, version

I am just about complete building an application.  I've tested it on 1.6-2.3 android versions.  My concern is how to distribute it.  Does each phone already have the google apis installed?  In particular one portion of my application is using the com.google.android.maps.* features.  When developing I have to use a separate google apis library for each android version.  Do I need to bundle the library for each version with my application?

Thanks in advance for any insight into this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does each phone already have the google apis installed?

No. However, I have not encountered any device that has the Android Market and does not have Google Maps. Hence, AFAIK, if you are only distributing via Android Market, most if not all of your users will have Google Maps.

> When developing I have to use a separate google apis library for each android version.

No, you don't.

The target you choose in your build process (e.g., the target option in Eclipse) needs to be one with Google Maps, so your references to `MapActivity` and such resolve. Beyond that, set your target to match the highest API you are trying to use.

> Do I need to bundle the library for each version with my application?

You are never bundling the library. The library is on the device.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that.  I was editing the properties and switching the library to match the OS version I was targeting.